# jQuery Mobile checkbox stay signed in

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I am doing jQuery Mobile, how to make the checkbox for "stay signed in" is same line with button login.

please refer my jsfiddle.net/mapsv3/sZdCu/
My goal is same interface with Google signin box like
[image: checkbox same line with button]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the grid/block classes from jquery mobile will allow you to inline your elements simply.

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a data-theme="d" id="loginButton" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" value="Login" href="booking.html" rel="external" >Login</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" data-mini="true">
        <label for="checkbox-1">Stay Signed in</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Romain, thanks for your reply. My another question is how to make the checkbox doesn't like a button (grey color box)

Comment: You can style the checkbox as you want it to be with CSS

Comment: you can add the property style="border:none;background:#EEE;" to the label element

Answer (score 0):

You could also add
data-role="none" this will remove the styling on the checkbox. I had to build something similar and it was quite hard.